# Remote File Upload with URL Parameters

Tags: 8, files

I'm currently using a digital asset management tool that allows us to host images as a CDN.

The DAM allows us to crop and position the image using URL parameters (example: https://embed.widencdn.net/img/du/ewjtweqh77/1800x714px/CampusScenics_0279.jpg?crop=yes&position=c), however, when I try to remote file upload (in entity browser) this image, I get an error message that tells me that the file has to be a .jpg or .png.

[image]

If you take a look at the URL, you can clearly see it's a .jpg image but for some reason, the validator is registering this as a non .jpg. I tried appending the last 3 characters of the URL (n=c) but that doesn't work, also there might be various different parameters depending on the image and how it's changed in the DAM so that wouldn't be a consistent solution even if it did.

Does anyone have any suggestions for this? I understand that I can embed this image in CKEditor but the solution for this ask needs to be an enhancement (or work around) to this remote file upload issue as we use this file upload process for all of our paragraph components.

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I tried the URL you had pasted in the question and then appended n=1.jpg to the end of the URL. It looks like the CDN provider does not care about additional querystrings. It also looks like the validator is expecting the extension to appear at the end of the URL. https://embed.widencdn.net/img/du/ewjtweqh77/1800x714px/CampusScenics_0279.jpg?crop=yes&position=c&n=1.jpg So it might work if you try by appending n=1.jpg at the end of the URL Can you please try and get back?

Comment: Hello @anoopjohn! I ended up trying the n=1 and it looks like this solution will allow images to now be accepted with URL parameters (woohoo - thank you!), however, it seems that the CDN link no longer crops to the appropriate size that is available in the parameters... Any thoughts on why this might be?

Comment: Perhaps the behavior has changed. The image gets resized per the resolution in the URL. Don't remember how it used to behave. But resize should work right? https://embed.widencdn.net/img/du/ewjtweqh77/300x200px/CampusScenics_0279.jpg?crop=yes